# Parent Div getting Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the postioning of the Div using jquery/javascript. I have a script to get the position of the Div whose class is 'content'. I am working in an ad company so when we upload the code in our server then a script is generated which we place in the html page. The script loads in the iframe and here our code executes.

My script was working fine locally. This is the method i used to get the positions of the Div.

```
function ReadDivPos(selector) {
        var _divPos = "";

        $(selector).each(function() {
            var p = $(this).offset();
            var w = $(this).width();
            console.log("Top " + p.top) //top
            console.log("left " + p.left) //left
            console.log("right " + p.left + w) //right
            console.log("offsetWidth " + w); //width

            _divPos += "Left " + p.left + ",Width " + w + ",Avail Width " + window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + (p.left + w) + "\\n";
        });
        return _divPos;
    }

    console.log(ReadDivPos(".content"));
```

It stopped working on the clients page then i realized i have to call the parent Div to get the values. I have search on google and found this code to get the parent div which i have modified to get my div.

```
             var parentDoc = window;
                while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
                    parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
                }
                parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
                var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
                var divs = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
                    if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {

                        console.log("Div Class :content ");
                }
                }
```

Now when i am using my code to get the positions of the div then it is not working

```
 function ReadDiv() {
     var parentDoc = window;
     while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
         parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
     }
     parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
     var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
     var divs = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
         if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {

             console.log("Div Class :content ");
             $(parentDiv[i].className).each(function() {
                 var p = $(this).offset();
                 var w = $(this).width();
                 console.log("Top " + p.top) //top
                 console.log("left " + p.left) //left
                 console.log("right " + p.left + w) //right
                 console.log("offsetWidth " + w); //width

                 _divPos += "Left " + p.left + ",Width " + w + ",Avail Width " + window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + (p.left + w) + "\\n";
             });
  return _divPos;
         }
     }
 }
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong here? HElp would be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some HTML code? It's really hard to tell what you're asking for.

Comment: @Locercus well i am trying to read the parent Div and then get the positions. I am able to read the Div class="content" i can read the inner HTML as well but in this part  $(parentDiv[i].className).each(function() { i am trying to read the values which i am not able to read it

Comment: I don't know your HTML structure and thus neither `parentDiv`. Please edit your post and add your HTML structure.